# clarifai2 java client. concept.name() results in Java NullPointerException but concept.value returns the confidence value

Tags: java, android, clarifai

When the `clarifai` API is called on an image it returns List of ClarifaiOutput Concepts. But on accessing the concepts only values can be accessed. Accessing name of the concepts results in `NullPointerException`.

concept.name() results in exception whereas concept.value() works fine

The Exception can be handled using a try catch block but I want to know the predicted concept names.

Please let me know what can be done to resolve this.

Below is the code for the same:

```
public void run() {
                List<String> ResultList = null;
                String ResultString = "";
                final List<ClarifaiOutput<Concept>> predictionResults = client.getDefaultModels().generalModel().predict().
                        withInputs(ClarifaiInput.forImage(new File(pictureFile.getAbsolutePath())))
                        .executeSync()
                        .get();
                if(predictionResults!=null && predictionResults.size()>0){
                    ListIterator<ClarifaiOutput<Concept>> itr= predictionResults.listIterator();
                    while(itr.hasNext()){
                        ClarifaiOutput<Concept> output = itr.next();
                        List<Concept> concepts = output.data();
                        if(concepts != null && concepts.size() > 0){
                            for (int j = 0; j < concepts.size(); j++) {
                                Concept concept = concepts.get(j);
                                float cval=0;
                                cval = concept.value();
                                if(cval > 0){
                                    ResultList.add(concept.name());
                                    ResultString += concept.name();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: That's a question which will require us to see the relevant code. Can you be a dear and post it here?

Comment: I have added the code. Please check it @sorak

Answer (score 0):

The NullPointerException is not due to concept.name() it is rather due to ResultList.add() method.

The ResultList needs to be initialized to avoid the exception

```
List<String> ResultList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

This will solve the issue